# Background color of 'Highlight Text' in WPF Datagrid cell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridcell

This is not the simple "IsSelected" background color of a datagrid row.  What I am referring to is when I am in a datagrid, that has editable data, I click in a given cell and have any text (for example an address), if I select part of the text, the HIGHLIGHT coloring is what I want to change...  I assume it would be part of the DataGridCell styling, but not sure where.

Comment: could you post a image showing what you want or what you don't?, I am bit lost in the description.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the [`TextBoxBase.SelectionBrush` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.selectionbrush.aspx).  From the linked page on MSDN:

> Gets or sets the brush that highlights selected text.

```
<TextBox SelectionBrush="Red" SelectionOpacity="0.5" 
    Foreground="Blue" CaretBrush="Blue">  
    This is some text.
</TextBox>
```

[image]

---

UPDATE >>>

You can apply this property in a `Style` that is applied to the `DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle` property, like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="Red" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: This may be for a textbox, but my issue is the textbox within a DataGrid individual cell.  Where in the DataGrid Cell template would this be set.